# Error Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm wondering how to unbundle the AVG and SUM functions in this sample script to remove this error "Aggregations of aggregations are not allowed"

```
SELECT 
  a.id,
  $DATEID_DATE(b.creation_date_id) AS creation_date,
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_id BETWEEN b.creation_date_id AND b.creation_date_id + 6 THEN a.ros END),
  AVG(CASE WHEN date_id BETWEEN b.creation_date_id AND b.creation_date_id + 6 THEN SAFE_DIVIDE(SUM(a.conv), SUM(a.cost)) END) 
FROM a
INNER JOIN
  b
  ON b.id = a.id
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: what is `$DATEID_DATE`? also what is the logic behind your `sum` and then `avg`?

Comment: Hi Mikhail #DATEID_DATE is just a macro I use to convert two different date formats between the two tables. I was summing up the sales (a.conv) & the cost of ads (a.cost), with a safe_divide I will get the return on ad spend for each ID then average out the results for the date range.

Comment: Can you provide a complete sample data and your expected output?